# How to enable or disable Hive support in spark-shell through Spark property (Spark 1.6)?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

Is there any configuration property we can set it to disable / enable Hive support through spark-shell explicitly in spark 1.6. I tried to get all the sqlContext configuration properties with,

```
sqlContext.getAllConfs.foreach(println)
```

But, I am not sure on which property can actually required to disable/enable hive support. or Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ## Spark >= 2.0
>
> Enable and disable of Hive context is possible with config
> `spark.sql.catalogImplementation`
>
> Possible values for `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` is
> ***in-memory*** or ***hive***
>
> [SPARK-16013 Add option to disable HiveContext in spark-shell/pyspark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16013)

---

## Spark < 2.0

Such a Spark property is **not** available in Spark 1.6.

One way to work it around is to remove Hive-related jars that would in turn disable Hive support in Spark (as Spark has Hive support when required Hive classes are available).

Comment: Thanks @Jacek Laskowski. The same i tried to recreate sqlContext object without HiveContext, as val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) which disables hive connection properties. Thanks.

Comment: So then I guess if you haven't fiddled around with `config`s, then on `Spark 2.x`, `spark-shell` already has `Hive`-support enabled as mentioned [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/144192/view.html) [or was that specifically for `HDP`?]

Comment: @y2k-shubham `spark-shell` enables Hive support by default so the trick is to use `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` on command line while launching it.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable hive support just by creating spark session but only in spark >=2.0:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark Hive Example")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

And here you can read how to configure hive on spark by changing hive and spark properties in hive-site.xml, spark-defaults.conf: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started - it must work with spark 1.6.1

Comment: Thanks @yehor Krivokon. Editing hive-site.xml or spark-defaults.conf should be required whenever i want to disable or enable hive in saprk 1.6.0, which is bit difficulty whenever i want to alter this hive enable.This is what i tried temporarily to serve my purpose, Recreate sqlContext without HiveContext like, val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc).

Comment: In this case I think it's really better to use spark 2.0+ where SparkSession is

Comment: @YehorKrivokon I am using spark-sql-2.3.1 version , how to get hiveContext ?

Comment: @user3252097 HiveContext is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0     
Use SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport instead.       
More info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.html

Comment: @Yehorkrivokon , thank you i have different error now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100404/how-to-fix-exception-while-running-locally-spark-sql-program-on-windows10-by-ena

Comment: @user3252097 I've answered on your new question, hope the answer will help you.

Comment: @YehorKrivokon sorry your answer is not useful as the error is coming on my windows machine

Comment: @RussS sir can you please have a look at the task. I am still geting the same error.....