# How to fix Exception while running locally spark-sql program on windows10 by enabling HiveSupport?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am working on `SPARK-SQL 2.3.1` and
I am trying to enable the hiveSupport for while creating a session as below

```
.enableHiveSupport()
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "c://tmp//hive")
```

I ran below command

```
C:\Software\hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin>winutils.exe chmod 777  C:\tmp\hive
```

While running my program getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)

How to fix this issue and run my local windows machine?

Comment: @Khal Dorgo Can you help me with this

Comment: I got this fixed using - winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this command:

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive/
```

This is Spark Exception, not Windows. You need to set correct permissions for the HDFS folder, not only for your local directory.

Comment: sorry i am using my local windows system with eclipseIDE , i am running the program on the same ...not sure how linux commands work on windows?

Comment: when I set this ".enableHiveSupport()" then only i see this error.